# place condition on the input value via aftermap in the mapper profile

Tags: c#, automapper, mapper

I send a value through Aftermap to profile mapper.

```
var provinces = await _repository.AsQueryable().ToListAsync();
var result = provinces.Select(item => _mapper.Map<GetProvincesDto>(item, x => x.AfterMap((src, dst) => dst.Language = "en"))).ToList();
```

Now, based on the value sent inside the profile, I want to Condition that if the value of the input language is English, I will map English names, and otherwise, I will map another value.

```
public class ProvinceToGetProvincesDto : Profile
{
    public ProvinceToGetProvincesDto()
    {
        CreateMap<Province, GetProvincesDto>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Id, x => x.MapFrom(x => x.Id))
            .ForMember(x => x.Name, x => x.MapFrom (x => x.language == "en" ? x.EnglishName.Value : x.Name.Value));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I have an error in x=>x.language. 'Province' does not contain a definition for 'language' and no accessible extension method 'language' accepting a first argument of type 'Province' could be found

Comment: How can I pass a value to the profile through aftermap and use it? @PalleDue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that there is not possible to pass the value outside of the mapping profile to perform the mapping.

What you do with the `.AfterMap()` is correct direction, just need to modify your mapping profile (rule) and `AfterMap` action.

```cs
public class ProvinceToGetProvincesDto : Profile
{
    public ProvinceToGetProvincesDto()
    {
        CreateMap<Province, GetProvincesDto>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Id, x => x.MapFrom(x => x.Id))
            .ForMember(x => x.Name, x => x.MapFrom(x => x.Name.Value));
    }
}
```

```cs
var result = provinces.Select(item => _mapper.Map<Province, GetProvincesDto>(item, opt =>
    {
        opt.AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Name = lang == "en" ? src.EnglishName.Value : src.Name.Value);
    })
).ToList();
```

Reference: [Before and After Map Action](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html)

Comment: [Sample Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2ocotI)